# Safari preventDefault() is not working with AudioContext

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, onbeforeunload, audiocontext

When the user closes the browser tab, I am showing a dialog box with the help of "beforeunload" event. Following is the code I used.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.returnValue = "";
};
```

This code works in chrome, firefox in all cases. But when it comes to safari, dialog box doesn't show up if I created a GainNode using `audioContext.createGain()`. How do i show dialog box even after creating GainNode?

Comment: are you sure your audioContext is getting created even? Note that Safari might still prefix it as webkitAudioContext.

Comment: Yes, @PhilippHancke AudioContext is getting created. Following is the code I used for creating Gain Node.

`var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;
var localContext = new AudioContext();
var localInputPoint = localContext.createGain();`

The only problem is that the dialog box is not showing up when closing the browser tab. But when I remove **createGain()** statement dialog box is showing up. 
So is there any relationship between **createGain()** and **preventDefault()**?